# Xcode 12 universal static library

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode12, universal-binary

Im using https://github.com/justeat/JustLog to log the details. This pod is being used by the sdk universal static library. So when building the library it’s success and they libios.a also there.

I’m using standard architecture. And valid archs arm64 armv7 x86_x64

When I’m using this universal library in the Xcode project it’s says

Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
"*OBJC_CLASS*$_Logger", referenced from: LogzLogger
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64

Same issue for when running in simulator as well x86_x64 not found.

I tried setting build active architecture only to NO and try adding valid archs for pods as well in the sdk project.

But the issue remains stable. So what is the solution for this.

Is that library not build for arm 64 and x86_x64 ?

Or any issue with my cocoa pods version it’s the latest version of pods I’m using.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you run `file my_static_lib.a` to check whether it is a fat binary ?

Comment: @rustyMagnet yes along with that pod I’m using AFnetworking and realm as well these are working fine but only this one got this issue.

Comment: Have you checked the `Target Membership`?  (i.e. accidentally including the same static library multiple times or not at all?

Comment: Yeah not included for multiple times. when I’m checking for the lib.a it’s says universal binary with [arm_v7:current ar archive] [x86_x64] [arm64]

Answer (score 1):

you may check whether you have added $(inherited) , which will add linker flags generated in pods, to Other Linker Flags as below:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

connect your physical device and select that device and run or archive error will be gone

Comment: Yeah sdk is building successfully and but the issue is when I’m running the project by using this library it says the above issue. Even for device same. Architecture not found issue. Any issue with this library which is not build for arm 64 and _x86_x64?